# Sign PDF file with PKCS7 detached using smart card C#

Tags: c#, smartcard, pkcs#7

I have ID smart card with SDK, the SDK is signing the binary content of the file and returns signature as byte array.

I used PKCS7 detached method supported by the SDK, the private key is not accessible, how can I add the signature bytes array to the pdf file?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: In order to get help.You need to show the code that you have tried.

Comment: I tried iTextSharp, but it needs private key to sign the pdf document which I don't have, the SDK is signing the file (bytes []) and returning two options:
Signed bytes (attached): the signature is attached to the file bytes and when I write it back to file it will not be recognized by the Adobe reader.
Signed bytes (detached): Signature bytes detached from the file, and this is my chances here by adding the signature to the pdf, source of signature is array of bytes.